# misunderstanding of Voltage output of a 3-phase rectifier

Tags: rectifier, three-phase, ac-dc

I simulated a 3 phase rectifier :
[image]

I obtained V1 and V2 as plotted below :
[image]

I dont understand that waveform as i'm supposed to obtain a DC voltage.
Can someone explain me how it comes that i got this waveform ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are your three phases 120 degrees out of phase with each other?

Comment: Yes they are 120 degrees with each other

Comment: the axes on your waveform are a little unclear.

Comment: the resolution is horrible... why do we see 20 cycles of the same waveform but I can't even read the magnitude of the voltages? I am pretty sure that your waveform are in opposing sign meaning if you would do the voltage measurement between you would obtain an DC.

Comment: The circuit should be grounded at only one point.

Comment: Make your plot bigger so we can read the y-axis. I think that's just ripple and you haven't noticed it doesn't drop all the way down to zero. The extra ground on the left is mucking a bit with things though but shouldn't destroy it. You get better results without it.

Comment: What happens if you remove the ground from the AC sources?

Comment: Most simulators can handle more than one ground, CircuitLab will. As for the ground on the left, this would be correct for a Wye connection to a transformer. Not sure what the OP intended.

Comment: @Mattman944 Sure, for a wye connected transformer. But I don't think those setups have that neutral wire running all the way over to the output on the other side of the bridge.

Comment: @DKNguyen - ran plot with left ground removed, works much better, see edits.

Comment: The fact is that this schematic is a transcription of a real test bench, the 3ph sinusoidal power supply is the output of a Δ-Y transformer, the Y winding has a neutral point that we connect to the ground. Should i disconnect the right ground ?

Answer (score 3):

Your V2 polarity is backwards. You want the minus side on ground.

Your circuit is probably working. As it is, both of your outputs are plotting positive, and all you see is ripple. We need to see your plot axis labels to know for sure.

It works in CircuitLab (guessing at what you think that it should do)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa2b1m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Edit: Plot with left ground removed. DKNguyen is correct, it works much better without the ground on the left. Only a few tenths of a volt of ripple.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Mattman944
The fact is that this schematic is a transcription of a real test bench, the 3ph sinusoidal power supply is the output of a Δ-Y transformer, the Y winding has a neutral point that we connect to the ground. Should i disconnect the right ground ?

Comment: @TESLA - I don't know for sure. Others are saying that the *left* ground should be disconnected, this makes sense to me, but I am not an expert on this. You may need to ask another question. If you do, realize that many people only remain interested in a question for a few hours. If you don't respond to comments quickly people will lose interest. Also, link to this question.

Comment: you are right. Thank you for your answers.